# Laravel: Create an API Controller, model and migration in one line

Tags: laravel, model, controller, migration

This is what I use at the moment to create Controller and Model

```
php artisan make:controller API/name_of_controller --api --model=name_of_model
```

then create a migration

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

In the past before I started using API, I used to do this to create model, migration and controller in one single line

```
php artisan make:model Banana -mcr
```

Is there a way to do this with API controller?

Comment: "This is what I use at the moment" That or - `-mcr` then just delete `create` and `edit` methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think there is no existing command to do that. How you create them currently is the best solution

```
php artisan make:controller API/TestController --api --model=Test
# then
php artisan make:migration create_tests_table
```

Why?

```
php artisan help make:controller
php artisan help make:model
```

1. Currently there is no option to include a migration file when
   creating a controller first
2. And there is no option to specify a
   controllers name (e.g. `--controller=API/TestController` when using
   `make:model` command

Comment: Yes, your're right. I found another similar way but again it does not include migration:
php artisan make:controller BananaController -m Banana

Answer (score 8):

**Run this command**

```
php artisan make:model Banana -mcr
```

*-m, --migration Create a new migration file for the model.*

*-c, --controller Create a new controller for the model.*

*-r, --resource Indicates if the generated controller should be a resource controller*

```
php artisan make:model Banana -mcr
Banana created successfully.
Created Migration: 2017_06_03_150652_create_bananas_table
BananaController created successfully.
```

**OR**

```
php artisan make:model Banana -a
```

*where -a = all*

Comment: I never knew this as well. Very helpful. How do we do this with API Controller?

Comment: Thank you for your time in looking into this. However, I am looking for API Controller not a regular Controller.

Comment: please mark as verified this answer if its help to you Thank Yoy @NoOne

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer bro. However, I need an API. Please check API.

Comment: php artisan make:model Banana -a --api

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
php artisan make:model Banana -a --api
```